# Await response from post in Angular and return the value when it's available

Tags: angular, post, return-value

I have the following method, which sends data towards my backend and then gets data back regarding the mutations that happened (how many actual new rows were added to the database). However if I use my method like this, my response will be holding the value that I want.. my this.stats won't however. Probably happening because the value is assigned after I've returned the variable already.

**uploadfile.service.ts**

```
PostCourses(objArray : object[]) : CoursesAddedStats {
        this.http.post<CoursesAddedStats>('https://localhost:7125/api/courses', objArray, this.httpOptions)
          .subscribe((response : CoursesAddedStats) => {
            this.stats = response;
           });
        return this.stats;
      }
```

**add-course-component.ts**

```
readFile = (file: any) => {
    const fileReader : FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = (ev) => {
      const data = fileReader.result;
      var txtData = data!.toString();
      this.values = this.uploadFileService.upload(txtData);
      this.stats = this.uploadFileService.PostCourses(this.values);
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
    if (this.stats.courseInstancesAdded) {
      this.message = `There have been ${ this.stats.coursesAdded } new courses and ${ this.stats.courseInstancesAdded} new course instances added`
      this.showMessage = true;
    }
  }
```

Where I wanna use this:
**add-course-component.html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="getFile($event)"/>
<div>
<p
*ngIf="showMessage" 
>
{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

**courseaddedstats.ts**

```
export class CoursesAddedStats {
    coursesAdded: number = 0;
    courseInstancesAdded: number = 0;
}
```

Anyone has a suggestion on how to fix it, so my return this.stats actually does hold the response value when I return it?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you shared where do you want to use `this.stats`. Some context would help in providing you with maybe a better solution than the one you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've made some adjustments. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it into a promise and simply await it like this

```
async PostCourses(objArray : object[]) : Promise<CoursesAddedStats | nulll> {
        this.stats = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post<CoursesAddedStats>('https://localhost:7125/api/courses', objArray, this.httpOptions));
          
        return !!this.stats ? this.stats : null;
      }
```

The reason that you will always have to deal with **[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** or **[Observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)** is that the API call is asynchronous and function calls are synchronous and you cannot hold the Js thread until the call is resolved and even if you can, the whole UI would be blocked for the time call is being **resolved**

**CONCLUSION:**

1. Either use promise to await
2. Use observable + async pipe method

Comment: I've managed to make it work by changing my PostCourses to return a Promise as suggested and then call the .then(x => this.stats = x) after the initial call to this method.
Thanks for the insights and help!